# Paragraph element forces text to jump to next line when I shrink the browser window?

Tags: html, css, browser, paragraph

I have a normal paragraph element within the body element, which contains multiple lines of text that when the browser window is shrunk, forces the text to the jump to the next line.

I don't want this to happen but for it have a defined and constant structure of how many lines the text takes up.

And when I shrink the browser window, I want it to stay like that in the same place so it just cuts some of it off the screen rather than it moving along with the edge of the browser.

Thank you.

here's my code:

```
p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My HTML atm is literally a body element and a paragraph element atm with text inside it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to prevent text from wrapping. Add `white-space: nowrap`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to give the element [min-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width).

```
p {
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: @koz No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to have the paragraph take up the same amount of horizontal space no matter the size of the window, you're probably looking for the `width` property:

```
p {
  width: 500px;
}
```